# Remove space before "]" using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stripping out parts of a string in JavaScript.  Unfortunately at times it leaves me with a blank space before a closing bracket `]` that I need.

For example, `[shortcode type="default"]` becomes `[shortcode ]`, whereas I need it to be `[shortcode]`.  Please note, there are multiple occurrences within the one string as the codes are built-up.

I need to strip out that blank space, if it occurs, before each occurrence of a `]` combination.  What is the regular expression for this?

Comment: What do you mean "stripping out parts of a string in **jQuery**"?  ([related](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif))

Comment: I don't want the default values that are populated into the form.  So I'm stripping those out using $.map and join.  If the default, as shown above, is in the beginning of the shortcode, I'm left with a space before the closing bracket.  I need to remove that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead.

```
str = str.replace(/\s+(?=])/g, "");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nVQmq/).

Comment: @user28254 Your question is *Remove space before “]” using Regular Expressions*. If you want to remove the `]` too, then capture it in the regex.

Comment: Alex, duh on my part.  I failed to restore it back into the variable, as you so kindly pointed out.  Problem solved.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If appearance of multiple spaces is possible, you should use `\s+`, like this:

```
str.replace(/\s+]/g, "]")
```

`g` at the end of `/.../` does what you're asking for: replacing multiple occurrences in each line.

Comment: Escaping `]` is not necessary (when not preceded by a `[`).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single space and a single occurrence, `.replace(' ]', ']')` is sufficient, but you say specifically that there will be more than one, so `.replace(/ ]/g, ']')` will do.  If there can be more than one space before the closing brace, use:

```
.replace(/\s+]/g, ']')
```

Comment: Sorry.  What I mean is there may be multiple occurrences of the ' ]' situation within a string. I need to replace each of these with ']'.